# Selenium - visibility_of_element_located: __init__() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, pytest

I am getting this error in my test code that uses Selenium Python Bindings:

```
>           twitter_campaigns = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located(By.CSS_SELECTOR, TWITTER_CAMPAIGNS))
E           TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)
```

And this is what Im executing:

```
class TestTwitter(TestLogin, TestBuying):

    def setup(self, timeout=10):
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
        self.driver.get(BASEURL)
        self.driver.implicitly_wait(timeout)

    def test_campaigns_loaded(self, timeout=10):
        self.signin_action()
        self.view_twitter_dashboard()
        self.select_brand()
        wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver, timeout)
        twitter_campaigns = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located(By.CSS_SELECTOR, TWITTER_CAMPAIGNS))
        assert True == twitter_campaigns

    def teardown(self):
        self.driver.close()
```

So I'm wondering Why Im getting the above errors, on all the classes I haven't defined an `__init__()` method instead I defined a setUp and tearDown methods as pytest follow. Any ideas why is taking 3 args?

Comment: Can you show us a full traceback?

Comment: I think there is just enough information to diagnose the problem, as I did it already.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The question you should be asking is **not** "why is it taking 3 args", but "**what** is taking 3 args". Your traceback refers to a very specific line in code, and it is there where the problem lies.

According to the [Selenium Python](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html) docs here, the [`selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.visibility_of_element_located`](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/80adb709873815b88bb57494a6908f8b86285766/py/selenium/webdriver/support/expected_conditions.py#L115) should be called with a tuple; it is not a function, but actually a class, whose *initializer* expects just 1 argument beyond the implicit `self`:

```
class visibility_of_element_located(object):
   # ...
   def __init__(self, locator):
       # ...
```

Thus, you need to call the `visibility_of_element_located` with two nested parentheses:

```
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located( ( By.CSS_SELECTOR, TWITTER_CAMPAIGNS ) ))
```

Which means that instead of 3 arguments `self`, `By.CSS_SELECTOR` and `TWITTER_CAMPAIGNS`, the `visibility_of_element_located.__init__` will be invoked with just expected 2 arguments: the implicit `self` and the locator: a `(type, expression)` tuple.

Comment: Wow!!! thanks, I missed one set of "()" so having it like:
    ((By.CSS_SELECTOR, TWITTER_CAMPAIGNS))) - got it working. And the reason is that EC (Expected_Condition) is a class, so my mistake was that I was passing 2 args to the EC class instead of passing the attributes for the visibility_of_element_located method. Thanks!!!

Comment: Nope, `expectedcondition` is a module. `visibility_of_element_located` is a class (yes, it is very confusing).