# Selenium: waiting for an element to load

Tags: python, html, selenium

I am still new to Selenium so sorry for stupid questions. I've been trying to find a way to get selenium to wait until an element is loaded in. The element is in a pop-up `<div>` and I need to scroll to the bottom to infinitely load the pop-up `<div>`. On Selenium's docs they say to use `WebdriverWait` like this:

```
while i <= 1000:
    try:
        #The xpath for the element I am trying to scroll to
        xpath = '/html/body/div[16]/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/ul/li[' + str(i) +']'

        #Selenium's way of waiting for the presence of an element
        element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located(By.XPATH, xpath))

        #Scrolling to that element
        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", element)
        i += 10

    except:
        print('Failed', i)

    time.sleep(2)
```

The `WebdriverWait` doesn't seem to be working. If I were to just scroll down and use `time.sleep(2)` to wait for the element to load. it works. However the page I am trying to load is not lazily loading things that have already been loaded. So the html is storing ALL the loaded elements in the pop-up `<div>` and it would be nice to scroll down as soon as the div is updated. The bigger the div gets, the longer the next load takes. I guess I'm looking for a dynamic wait for Selenium if that exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually just solved it. I was browsing other methods in the `excepted_conditions` class and found `visibility_of_element_located`. A quick stack search and I found this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23661734/selenium-visibility-of-element-located-init-takes-exactly-2-arguments). When passing the arguments to the `expected_conditions` class it is expecting a tuple, not the 2 arguments. The CORRECT way to use WebdriverWait is like this:

```
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, xpath)))
```

Those damn parentheses can get ya.

Answer (score 2):

You can refer to the **implicit waits** in selenium.
The implicit wait will instruct the web driver to wait for certain amount of time before it throws a "No Such Element Exception". (Implicit Wait time is applied to all the elements in the script for a session)

you can implement it like below:-

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10,TimeUnit.SECONDS) ;
```

It means that if the element is not located on the web page within that time frame (10 seconds), it will throw an exception.

2. Other wait in Selenium is Explicit Wait.
   The explicit wait is used to tell the Web Driver to wait for certain conditions (Expected Conditions) or the maximum time exceeded before throwing an "ElementNotVisibleException" exception.

you can implement it like below

```
WebDriverWait wait=new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);

wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[contains(text(),'STACKOVERFLOW')]")));
```

***As in your case it is related to alerts try using `***

```
 wait.until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent());
```

3. Last wait to help you in selenium is Fluent Waits

It defines the frequency with which WebDriver will check if the condition appears before throwing the “ElementNotVisibleException”.

Simply saying, Fluent Wait looks for a web element repeatedly at regular intervals(defined by you) until timeout happens or until the object is found.

And you should use it when you try to test the presence of an element that may appear after x seconds/minutes.

to implement fluent wait try below sample code:-

```
 Wait<WebDriver> wait = new FluentWait<WebDriver>(driver)
.withTimeout(20, SECONDS)
.pollingEvery(5, SECONDS)
.ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class);

WebElement foo = wait.until(new Function<WebDriver, WebElement>() 
{
    public WebElement apply(WebDriver driver) {
    return driver.findElement(By.id("STACK011"));
}
});
```